# SVG makes white line in browser at certain size

Tags: svg

when rendering my SVG image in chrome it displays a very thin diagonal white line (even outside of it's box when I inspect it).

[This is what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGMao.png)

It does this nowhere else on the website, just here. Why does this happen and how do I remove the thin white line?

[Link to SVG](http://svgshare.com/i/2aT.svg)

Thanks!

Comment: You're preserving the aspect ratio of the image. Do you want to do that or not. If you do how do you want the image to display when its container is a different aspect ratio to the image itself?

Comment: @RobertLongson I know how that works. I think you misunderstood my problem. Look at the first image, it has a thin diagonal white stripe crossing the "be" in "youtube". It's coming from the SVG for some weird reason.

Comment: Remove elements from the image till you find out what's causing it.

Comment: If you need further help, please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Ie. a live version, not a screenshot.

Comment: Issue is described [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=691262). It's a chrome/gpu problem.